# image upload and cropping

Tags: php

How can we upload and crop the image using PHP.

Comment: Seems like a question you could google for..?

Comment: http://www.talkphp.com/advanced-php-programming/1709-cropping-images-using-php.html

Comment: Step 1: Visit http://google.com - Step 2: Type in "upload and crop image using php" - Step 3: Click the Google Search button

Comment: Thanx to reply!
Ok fine! i have another question.
I have a website in which i am giving security like login id and password( as usual). No what i want is that, 
1) I don't want to allow a single user to login in different machine at the same time.
2) For this i am using a column in database which is keeping the current status of user(i.e. loging/logout). I am allowing user to login only when has session has not closed and status is login.
3) So my problem is that when i am logging out manually. it is closing the session as well as updating the database with status "logout".

Comment: 4) but when i am closing the window from Cross buttonat top right corner. it is closing the ssion but table data is still "login". so later on i can't be able to login into the same user.
5) So how could i solve this problem.
Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See:

**[PHP & jQuery image upload and crop](http://www.webmotionuk.co.uk/php-jquery-image-upload-and-crop/)**

Comment: Can you help me in another question what i asked in just prvious comment?
Once again thanx.

Comment: @user356170: You should ask that question separately as it is different one and you are likely to get more answers for that.